# How do I go about writing a device driver for Android

Tags: android, driver

Regarding this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220778/linux-multifunction-composite-gadget

Assuming that no driver exists, how does one go about creating a device driver so that a usb device that was previously unknown to Android, can be read?

Comment: Possibly related project: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Comment: That git hub project does not work with the linux multifunction gadget device. Is what you're saying is that it should be added?

Comment: The code is available at least as a reference to build your own. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, otherwise you should configure your Blackbone device's USB port as serial if you want to connect via Android.